# How can I enable highlighting of special method calls (eg inherited method, abstract method) for Groovy in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I want to make it more intuitive to recognize when a method call in a class I'm working on is inherited, or if it refers to an abstract method stub from the current class; really I want to easily be able to tell when a particular method call has been implemented in the current class.

How could I do this?

I've looked at the Color scheme settings in IntelliJ for Groovy, and can't see anything that would let me do this.  The Java scheme settings at least have an option to style inherited method calls, but I can't find anything similar for Groovy.

Comment: It's not supported at the moment. Feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.